# Export data from one Google sheet to another, but allow for editing without re-importing rows

Tags: import, google-sheets

I'm just going to start this by saying this is my first ever post here, so please excuse me if I've missed something!

I'm working on a project in Google Sheets that allows users to submit links that need to be looked over by an admin, upon which they're marked and copied to a new sheet for a second round of looking over by a different admin. At the moment users submit the link via a form which leads into a sheet (Sheet1). Once it's looked at by an admin they tag it "Accepted" or "Commented". If it's accepted it's moved into "Sheet2", where a different admin will need to publish the answer. If it's commented on then edits are needed and it's moved to "Sheet3", and again it's passed to a new admin.

Ideally once the process is complete I'd like the admins to be able to remove rows from Sheet2 and Sheet3 (without removing them from Sheet1) so as to cut down on the size, as there's often hundreds of entries a week and creating a new setup every few months to prevent lag is a pain. The problem is deleting them without them being re-imported or breaking the import range. **I can't seem to find a solution that will import each row once (and only once) from Sheet1, rather than constantly updating as new rows come in to include the old deleted ones again along with the new ones.**

If it helps this is the formula I'm using to pull rows into Sheet2 right now (import link removed for security, of course) =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheet link" , "Sheet1!A2:F"),"SELECT * WHERE Col6='Accepted'")
This works fine until you try to delete a row, wherein it's immediate re-added.